# Как сделать график mathplotlib над виджетом PyQt, а не наоборот?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, matplotlib

Из виджета вызывается график, всё хорошо работает. Но график над виджетом, и его невозможно закрыть без закрытия самого виджета. Соответственно вопрос - как сделать, чтобы он был 'над', а не 'под'?

И ещё вопрос - можно ли ограничить количество графиков, т.е. чтобы кнопка 'get plot' вызывала график только 1 раз? Ну т.е. типа применить singleton?

```
self.btn1 = QPushButton("Get plot", self)
self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.make_plot)  
def make_plot(self):
    sizes  = self.country_and_club_eng_statistics.date_for_plot()[1]   
    labels = self.country_and_club_eng_statistics.date_for_plot()[0]
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.pie(sizes, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax1.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.